# Shorten kubectl jq command

Tags: json, optimization, jq

I am iterating over `kubectl` output that looks similar to this:

```json
{
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "Pod",
      "metadata": {
        "name": "ubuntu1",
        "namespace": "development-namespace1",
      },
   ],
    {
      "kind": "Pod",
      "metadata": {
        "name": "ubuntu2",
        "namespace": "development-namespace2",
      },
   ],
}
```

I am trying to learn `jq`, but my command to get a value out of the first dictionary is really long:

```bash
kubectl get pods -o json -A | jq '.items | .[] | select(.metadata.name == "ubuntu1")  | .metadata.namespace'
```

How can I shorten this?

Comment: You've changed `.name` to `.namespace` in your filter, so the one from my previous comment isn't valid anymore. In the new version you can still factor out `.metadata`, though: `.items[].metadata | select(.name == "ubuntu1").namespace`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- This answer assumes:

  - Linux version: Debian 12 bookworm
  - `jq` version: `1.6`
  - Kubernetes version: `1.28.3`

---

## Iterate over an array nested in a dict keyed by 'items'

Using this (abbreviated) json output dumped from `kubectl get pods -o json -A`...

```json
{
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "Pod",
      "metadata": {
        "name": "ubuntu1",
        "namespace": "development-namespace1",
      },
   ],
    {
      "kind": "Pod",
      "metadata": {
        "name": "ubuntu2",
        "namespace": "development-namespace2",
      },
   ],
}
```

As [@pmf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2158479/pmf) said in a comment, you can select the value of a key nested in that array using this:

```bash
jq '.items[] | select(.metadata.name == "ubuntu1").metadata.namespace'
```

### Explanation

- `.items[]` returns the array keyed by `items`
- `select(.metadata.name == "ubuntu1")`:

  - searches all the dicts
  - finds the dict matching the nested key: `metadata.name` and value: `ubuntu1`
- `select(.metadata.name == "ubuntu1").metadata.namespace` returns value of the `.metadata.namespace` in the selected dictionary

To reiterate, `jq '.items[] | select(.metadata.name == "ubuntu1")` returns:

```json
{
  "metadata": {
    "name": "ubuntu1",
    "namespace": "development-namespace1",
  }
}
```

---

## Bonus material, use jq for any shell command with columns

### Parse 'ps' output

Assume you want to parse the output of the ps command...

Assume `ps | <insert-sed-jq-pipe-here>` returns the following...

```bash
$ ps | <insert-sed-jq-pipe-here>
    PID TTY          TIME CMD
  11899 pts/0    00:00:18 bash
2694259 pts/0    00:00:00 ps
2694260 pts/0    00:00:00 sed
2694261 pts/0    00:00:00 jq
$
```

You can convert any columnized text to json with:

```bash
jq -sR '[sub("\n$";"") | splits("\n") | sub("^ +";"") | [splits(" +")]]'
```

#### Parse 'ps' output as json

This example will dump the aforementioned `ps` as json...

```bash
$ ps | sed -ne '/PID/,$ p' | jq -sR '[sub("\n$";"") | splits("\n") | sub("^ +";"") | [splits(" +")]]'
[
  [
    "PID",
    "TTY",
    "TIME",
    "CMD"
  ],
  [
    "11899",
    "pts/0",
    "00:00:18",
    "bash"
  ],
  [
    "2694259",
    "pts/0",
    "00:00:00",
    "ps"
  ],
  [
    "2694260",
    "pts/0",
    "00:00:00",
    "sed"
  ],
  [
    "2694261",
    "pts/0",
    "00:00:00",
    "jq"
  ]
]
$
```

### Parse 'top' output as json

You can even use this technique on `top`... but `top` looks a little tricky at first because:

- It's interactive by default
- You get extra text before the `PID` column header.... example:

```bash
$ top -bn 1 | head -n 8
top - 08:54:54 up 14 days,  1:13,  0 user,  load average: 0.11, 0.22, 0.30
Tasks:  96 total,   1 running,  95 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0.0 us,  6.7 sy,  0.0 ni, 93.3 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem :   3767.1 total,    109.5 free,   2140.8 used,   1990.5 buff/cache
MiB Swap:   1024.0 total,    898.2 free,    125.8 used.   1626.4 avail Mem

    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
2371290 root      20   0 1931856  48168  27024 S   6.7   1.2   0:30.64 flanneld
$
```

You can solve the interactive `top` problem with `top -bn 1`, which will run top once in non-interactive mode.

Finally, that same `sed` we used in the `ps` command will strip off the lines before the `top` `PID`... so the final `top` command as json is:

```bash
$ top -bn 1 | sed -ne '/PID/,$ p' | jq -sR '[sub("\n$";"") | splits("\n") | sub("^ +";"") | [splits(" +")]]'

... insert-top-json-output-here
$
```